# Как при создание таблицы в read bean PHP не создавать столбец `id`

Tags: php, mysql

Суть в том что если я создаю таблицу через read bean php всегда создается столбец id который мне вовсе не нужен, как сделать так чтобы read bean не создавал его автоматически

Comment: Зачем? Если он создаёт его безусловно, значит, всегда считает, что такой столбец в структуре есть. И его не-создание (или удаление) может привести к неприятностям там, где ты их совсем не ждёшь. Пусть его мотается, всё одно места на него надо не так уж и много. Ну или удали - и жди, где оно тебе аукнется.

Answer (score -1):

Redbean создан в расчёте на то, что столбец id обязательно должен присутствовать в таблице связанной с объектами, которые отражаются на базу. Например, в коде класса [RedBeanPHP\Repository](https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/master/RedBeanPHP/Repository.php#L351) можно найти метод `check`, который бросает исключение, если id не определён:

```
if ( !isset( $bean->id ) ) {
    throw new RedException( 'Bean has incomplete Meta Information id ' );
}
```

К сожалению, код библиотеки написан так, что вы не можете просто расширить Repository и переопределить эту логику. Если вы уже достаточно хорошо разбираетесь как работает ваша база данных и хотите иметь больше контроля над логикой отображения объектов в бд, то вам надо отказаться от Redbeans.

Обратите внимание, что например для таблиц подсистемы хранения InnoDB в MySQL (MariaDB) первичный ключ [создаётся](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html), даже если вы не указываете его явно. Если вы поняли о чём это я, то можете выбросить Redbean. Если впервые слышите, то не спешите отказываться от этой ORM, её ограничения -- цена за простой интерфейс и универсальность.